# Build failed but the errors in not shown in the error list ( visual studio 2019 )

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build an application in visual studio , the build is failed but I can't see any error in the error list.
I have tried:

- Clean solution.
- Delete vs folder.
- Restart Visual studio

But any of those solutions solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything showin in the Output window?

Comment: Yes , there is.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Please who the content of the output window.

Comment: I can't understand you

Comment: Please add the content of the build-output to your question

Comment: The output show me the errors , but the error list does not show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears in the output window.

Try to clear the solution then you close Visual Studio then you delete **bin** and **obj** folders. Then you restart Visual Studio ... it may takes a moment and it will build or fails and display the error.